# Custom Facelets-Tag with multiple Child-Components in h:panelGrid

Tags: java, jsf, tags, facelets, uicomponents

I have written a custom tag extending `UIComponentBase`.
It adds multiple Child-Components (`UIComponent`) during the `encodeBegin` method.

For layouting purposes, I'd like to nest this Child-Components in a `h:panelGrid`,
but the tag gets in the way here.

**`ExampleTag.java`**

```
private ExampleTag extends UIComponentBase {

    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        getChildren().add(new HtmlLabel());
        getChildren().add(new HtmlOutputText();
    }
}
```

**`ExampleOutput.xhtml`**

```
<html>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
       <foo:exampleTag />
       <foo:exampleTag />
    </h:panelGrid>
</html>
```

The generated output would have the `HtmlLabel` and `HtmlOutput` components in the **same cell**,
but I'd like to have them in one row, i.e. **two cells**.

Comment: @user745359: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** I recommend you to change your name and (optionaly) your picture. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `h:panelGrid` only controls the layout of its own children (and not the children of its children)
2. each `<foo:exampleTag />` creates one composite control (with its own children)

If you want to add multiple controls to a `h:panelGrid`, use one of the other template mechanisms.

For example, this `h:panelGrid` uses a [`ui:include`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html):

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <ui:include src="gridme.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="foo" value="Hello,"/>
        <ui:param name="bar" value="World!"/>
      </ui:include>
      <ui:include src="gridme.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="foo" value="Hello,"/>
        <ui:param name="bar" value="Nurse!"/>
      </ui:include>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

The included [composition](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/composition.html) file:

```
<!-- gridme.xhtml -->
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:outputText value="#{foo}" />
  <h:outputText value="#{bar}" />
</ui:composition>
```

A subset of the view output:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Hello,</td>
<td>World!</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello,</td>
<td>Nurse!</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

*Take care with the above implementation - you cannot set IDs explicitly on anything in `gridme.xhtml` as there is no composite control and therefore no `NamespaceContainer` to ensure children are namespaced uniquely.*

---

A component is not a tag.

```
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
  getChildren().add(new HtmlLabel());
  getChildren().add(new HtmlOutputText();
}
```

This is **not** an acceptable way to build a composite control. If you do this, new controls will be added to the component every time it is rendered. You should also not do this in the constructor; that would lead to problems too. There is no good way to add child controls within a control; it should be done externally by the view (see above) or [a tag](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/Tag.html).

Comment: Thanks alot, this was a fundamental design error then. I "fixed" the adding of components in the render phase by checking the childCount(), which isn't a good idea either!